# MYSQL/PHP Select A Users Ranks

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

Hi I have A MYSQL Database Thats Like This

```
|id|username|password|rank  |
|1 | jeff   | Passwor| admin|
|2 | bob    | passow | user |
```

how would i use php to fetch it and assign it a variable

Comment: Google `mysqli`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You could use some code

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help your problem

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "contoh";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM `user_ranks`';
  $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
      while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
          $id = $row['id'];
          $username = $row['username'];
          $password = $row['password'];
          $rank = $row['rank'];
      }
```